# open multiple instances of a NSWindow

Tags: cocoa, nswindow

I am building a chat application, for which I have an outlet for a `NSWindow`. Now I want to open multiple instances of the window. How do I do it? I'm not using *window controller*. `makeKeyAndOrderFront`: methods opens only one *instance*.

Please help me I couldn't find it anywhere

Comment: please help instead of changing fomatting

Comment: best solved using a NSWindowController and instantiate one per window. Each instance then loads the NIB with the window and opens it. You can't make a second instance of the same window within your NIB.

Comment: i tried that too but then I'm unable to set the outlets of the window. suppose I'm taking another sub class of NSWindow allong with the NSWindowController. how do I set that particular class whith the windowcontroller?

Comment: From your comment I guess that your app design might be the problem. capsule the logic in the window controller and then the hooking up shouldn't be the problem

Answer (score 3):

So I know this question is old but I'm going to answer it anyway because I struggled with this and there's not a lot of information out there about it.

You need to keep every window in scope so it doesn't get garbage collected. You can do this with a collection of NSWindowControllers. I put this collection in AppDelegate.swift which is probably wrong, but I can't see anywhere else to put it, other than the main window controller, which would also be wrong.

You can declare it like this:

```
var exampleListOfWindows = [NSWindowController]()
```

You need to programmatically create new windows and then add them to your collection.

You can do that with a function like this:

```
func openNewWindow(someParameter: String) {

    let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil)

    if let exampleViewController = storyboard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("exampleStoryboardId") as? ExampleViewController{

        let newWindow = NSWindow(contentViewController: exampleViewController)

        // you'll probably need to pass your window some data and because I hate myself I choose to do it like this
        exampleViewController.passSomeDataToNewWindowFunction(someParameter)

        newWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)

        let controller = NSWindowController(window: newWindow)
        exampleListOfWindows.append(controller)
        controller.showWindow(self)

    }
}
```

Comment: So in other words, to stop the NSWindow instance from being immediately released by ARC, you are storing the window instances in a mutable array? And then when you open/close a window, you add/remove a window instance from the array. This enables you to not override the current window instance, when you open a new one. Am I correct?